# Can Visual Studio build a .NET assembly with a different simple name than its file name?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-assembly

The documentation for [the `System.Reflection.AssemblyName.Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.name?view=netframework-4.7.1) states:

> Gets or sets the simple name of the assembly. This is usually, but not necessarily, the file name of the manifest file of the assembly, minus its extension.

I'm curious about the non-usual case here. Of course, you could have the assembly file renamed after-the-fact, and the original file name would stay as the simple name in the metadata. But is that the only caveat this documentation implies, or is there a "legitimate" way to create an assembly whose filename differs from its simple name?

---

Through a reading of the a default targets files used by Visual Studio C#/VB.NET projects (`<MSBuild install location>\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`), I thought this was the intent of the `AssemblyName` and `TargetName` properties, as implied by this excerpt ("..." comments for where I abridged the excerpt, other comments come as-is from the file):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Ensure any OutputPath has a trailing slash, so it can be concatenated -->
  <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutputPath)')">$(OutputPath)\</OutputPath>
  <AssemblyName Condition=" '$(AssemblyName)'=='' ">$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>

  <!-- ... -->

</PropertyGroup>

<!-- ... -->

<PropertyGroup>

  <TargetName Condition="'$(TargetName)' == '' and '$(OutputType)' == 'winmdobj' and '$(RootNamespace)' != ''">$(RootNamespace)</TargetName>
  <TargetName Condition=" '$(TargetName)' == '' ">$(AssemblyName)</TargetName>
  <!-- Example, MyAssembly -->

  <!-- ... -->

  <TargetFileName Condition=" '$(TargetFileName)' == '' and '$(OutputType)' == 'winmdobj'">$(WinMDExpOutputWindowsMetadataFilename)</TargetFileName>
  <TargetFileName Condition=" '$(TargetFileName)' == '' ">$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)</TargetFileName>

  <!-- Example, MyAssembly.dll -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

`TargetName` appears to be the name of the file that the build will produce, without the extension, and it's set to the value of `AssemblyName` by default.

So, I set `TargetName` in my project file `MyProjectName.csproj` (excerpt, these properties are not defined anywhere else in this file):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
  <RootNamespace>MyNamespace</RootNamespace>
  <AssemblyName>MyAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
  <TargetName>MyTargetName</TargetName>
  <!-- ... -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

My assembly's code (C#):

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClassName
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Type myType = typeof(MyClassName);
            Console.WriteLine($"myType.FullName:\r\n\t{myType.FullName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"myType.AssemblyQualifiedName:\r\n\t{myType.AssemblyQualifiedName}");

            var myAsm = myType.Assembly;
            Console.WriteLine($"myAsm.FullName:\r\n\t{myAsm.FullName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"myAsm.CodeBase:\r\n\t{myAsm.CodeBase}");

            var myAsmName = myAsm.GetName(false);
            Console.WriteLine($"myAsmName.Name:\r\n\t{myAsmName.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"myAsmName.CodeBase:\r\n\t{myAsmName.CodeBase}");
        }
    }
}
```

When built, Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.6) produces a file named `MyTargetName.exe`, as I would expect. However, when I run the assembly, I see that the assembly's simple name is now *also* `MyTargetName`, instead of the intended `MyAssemblyName`:

```
myType.FullName:
        MyNamespace.MyClassName
myType.AssemblyQualifiedName:
        MyNamespace.MyClassName, MyTargetName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
myAsm.FullName:
        MyTargetName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
myAsm.CodeBase:
        file:///C:/code/MySolutionName/MyProjectName/bin/Debug/MyTargetName.exe
myAsmName.Name:
        MyTargetName
myAsmName.CodeBase:
        file:///C:/code/MySolutionName/MyProjectName/bin/Debug/MyTargetName.exe
```

I made a text search through the entire MSBuild installation file tree's `.targets` and `.props` files and it doesn't look like `AssemblyName` is ever set to the value of `TargetName`. (I searched `<AssemblyName` to catch when it would be set by a property group, and `"AssemblyName"` to catch when it would be set by the output of a call to a task.) This is the only other line I found, in `<MSBuild install location>\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props`:

```
<AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
```

But I don't think this line is being used for my test project, because then I would expect the assembly's simple name to be `MyProjectName`, not `MyTargetName`.

Comment: It is a tricky implementation detail, but the CLR avoids having to know anything about assembly names, lookup and the GAC.  It delegates that job to a separate api called "Fusion".  It is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233169(v=vs.100).aspx), a custom fusion implementation could return whatever it want for IAssemblyName::GetName().  I'm not aware of such customizations.

Comment: What happens if you make that project an dll instead of an .exe?

Comment: @CJohnson There's no apparent change after switching the project from a Console Application (EXE) to a Class Library (DLL) and calling the code from another executable.